# In Spellsword, can equipment boost maxed skills?

Tags: spellsword

All skills have a maximum level where no more levels can be bought with rupees. If I reach that level, then equip items that provide a bonus to that skill, does the bonus still apply (exceeding the "max")? Or is the bonus just wasted?

Comment: Just bought this game as I'm curious to find the answer. As soon as I know it, I will post. Although chances are, you probably know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If you do not wish to read the entire answer, the short answer is "**No**". If you do, however, then thank you for taking the time to
>   read and I hope you enjoy reading about it as much as I did writing
>   it.

I decided to test this out using the spell card "Wind". The spell card's description when leveling it up:

> **Increase wind range and wind size**

The first part of my research was to test out the spell card when it was one level before the maximum, without using any equipment boosts. Here are the results:

[image: One Level Before The MAX]

Take note of the size of the wind. When I level up wind so that it is at the maximum, the wind range and wind size should be increased. I will mainly be focusing on the wind size.

Here are the results of the spell card at the maximum level, with no equipment boosts. As you can see, this one is slightly larger.

[image: The Maximum Level]

I tried my best to take the screenshot while both were in the same area. I also tried to get the character in the same position by running all the way to the left and then lightly tapping the right arrow key.

Next, I added some equipment boosts to the next level in order to see if there would be any changes. I used **Spellmaster Cap** in my hat slot, which gives a **+1 to all cards**, including wind. For my necklace slot, I used **Thor's Hammer**, which gives a **+4 to all wind cards**. Finally, for my ring slot, I used **Hurricane**, which gives a **+2 boost to all wind cards**.

[image: Spellmaster's Cap]
[image: Thor's Hammer]
[image: Hurricane]

Here are the results of the wind card with a +6 boost.

[image: Max Wind Card with Boosts]

Now, to take a closer look at the green shapes and their sizes, I have zoomed in on each image, taking the photo in the exact same spot.

[image: One Level Before MAX, No Boosts]
[image: The Maximum Level]
[image: The Maximum Level with Boosts]

> From the first test to the second test, the size is larger, as expected. However, even with a +6 Boost (Which is a lot), there is not really a noticeable difference between the second and third test.

Comment: Good science! It's nice to see more in-depth answers for iOS games around here.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the game. Some levels were really frustrating though.